# C: fgets always NULL

Tags: c, io

I'm playing with file I/O in C.. I'm trying to use fgets to read data in from one file and output it to another file. The problem is that it always returns NULL and so nothing gets copied to the output file. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fpIn;
    FILE *fpOut;

    if ((fpIn = fopen("C:\\testIn.txt", "r") == NULL))
    {
        printf("Cannot open input file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((fpOut = fopen("C:\\testOut.txt", "a") == NULL))
    {
        printf("Cannot open output file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buffer[128];
    while (fgets(buffer, 128, fpIn) != NULL)
    {
        fputs(buffer, fpOut);
    }

    fclose(fpIn);
    fclose(fpOut);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

another thing; when I tried using "a+f" in the second arg for fopen, it didn't work.

Comment: You're sure that the input file exists and that you have permission to access it?

Comment: It most certainly exists and my account certainly has access to it, yes.. is there perhaps some restriction on the IDE accessing it? I am using CodeBlocks and I have administrator priviliges on my machine.

Comment: Did this code compile? It shouldn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if ((fpOut = fopen("C:\\testOut.txt", "a") == NULL))
```

Should be

```
if ((fpOut = fopen("C:\\testOut.txt", "a")) == NULL)
```

Same on the input file.
If you are new to C, I'd suggest do one thing at a time to make it easier to track down issues.
e.g.

```
fpOut = fopen("C:\\testOut.txt", "a");
if(fpOut == NULL) {
    ...
```

Comment: LOL I can't believe I didn't see that! Well done! Thank you.. you'll be getting marked as "answer" as soon as StackOverflow will let me.. (about 8 more mins)..

Comment: I'd suggest using a decent compiler with maximum warning options.

Comment: I'm using CodeBlocks..far better than my experience with DevC.. I would prefer VS2010, but it doesn't support C99. Have another suggestion?

Comment: @JimBalter: Warnings should not be necessary. Aside from the integer constant expression zero (which is a null pointer constant), integer expressions do not implicitly convert to pointers in C. If a compiler allows this implicit conversion, it's malevolent.

Comment: @R.. I realize that warnings should not be necessary in this case and that any compiler that allows this is malevolent, but since the OP didn't answer my question of whether the code compiled, I didn't want to make assumptions, so I simply advised to use a "decent" (as in non malevolent) compiler and to use maximum warning options which is good practice, especially for newbies. And my comment was a counterpoint to "do one thing at a time ..." which definitely should not be necessary here.

Comment: @Matt If your compiler accepted the code you posted, it's crap. Anything else, such as gcc, would do.

Comment: Are you sure gcc doesn't permit this invalid implicit conversion? Anyway the point of my comment was not to criticize your answer, just to criticize (imo malevolent) compilers.

Comment: I'd suggest never writing assignments in if () blocks. This doesn't improve the generated code any but adds plenty of opportunity for confusion.

Comment: @R.. gcc (with default flags) issues a warning about assigning an integer to a pointer without a cast. It still just issues a warning with --ansi --pedantic, so I think the language allows the assignment but I'm too lazy to go read the standard. Anyway, I do assignments in ifs all the time and never get confused or introduce this sort of error, in part because I read the warnings and don't allow them for my code, and in part because my brain knows where the parens go and such code immediately looks wrong.